# How can I include a scala operation between a sequence of database queries in Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Let's say I have a model that looks something like so:

```
case class User(username: String, dateOfBirth: Timestamp, lastSentGift: Timestamp)
```

Assuming I have an appropriate accompanying Slick schema, `Users`, how can I perform multiple queries against this table within a transaction, with a scala function to be called in between?

I've seen that Slick provides a `DBIOAction` and `DBIO.seq` to allow composition of multiple database operations within a single transaction, but I don't understand if/how I can use these with a scala function called in between.

For example, I'd like to do something such as this, but keep everything in a single transaction:

```
def prepareGiftFor(user: User): Timestamp = ???

val usersWithBirthdays = db.run(
  Users.filter { user => 
    user.dateOfBirth > (now - 1 month) && user.lastSentGift < (now - 1 month)
  }
  .limit(100)
  .forUpdate
)

usersWithBirthdays
  .map(user => (user.username, prepareGiftFor(user)))
  .map { case (username, lastSentGift) =>
    db.run(
      Users.withFilter(_.username === username)
        .map(row => row.lastSentGift)
        .update(lastSentGift)
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General idea of slick is to delay `db.run` call as much as possible. Preferred way is to work with `DBIOAction` instances and chain them as we do with scala `Future` or `Option`.

For this `DBIOAction` supports `map` and `flatMap` methods. [DBIOAction](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.2.3/slick/src/main/scala/slick/dbio/DBIOAction.scala) companion object also contains helper methods `from`, `successful` and `failed`. With them you can construct `DBIOAction` from primitive values. For more information check this section of [slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#composing-database-i-o-actions) about actions composition.

It's possible to run all sql quires in single transaction by calling [transactionally](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$JdbcActionExtensionMethods@transactionally:DBIOAction[R,S,EwithTransactional]) on `DBIOAction` instance.

Your example could be rewritten as:

```
def prepareGiftFor(user: User): Timestamp = ???

def findUsersWithBirthdays(): DBIO[Seq[User]] = {
  Users
    .filter { user =>
      user.dateOfBirth > (now - 1 month) && user.lastSentGift < (now - 1 month)
    }
    .limit(100)
    .forUpdate
}

def updateUsers(users: Seq[User]): Seq[DBIO[Int]] = {
  users
    .map(user => (user.username, prepareGiftFor(user)))
    .map {
      Users
        .withFilter(_.username === username)
        .map(row => row.lastSentGift)
        .update(lastSentGift)
    }
}

db.run(
  (for {
    users <- findUsersWithBirthdays()
    _ <- DBIO.sequience(updateUsers(users))
  } yield ()).transactionaly
)
```